# How do I get EntityFrameworkCore generated SQL to use the right format for DateTime objects?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I'm using [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer v2.1.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/2.1.2) (and have also tried v2.2.0-preview1-35029) and am using LINQ to fetch a collection of entities from an Azure SqlServer database, filtering on a DateTime field.

However, the SQL generated by the LINQ statement uses a string-based DateTime value that SqlServer rejects with this error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I can modify the SQL statement to change the datetime format so that the query works without error (see below for details), but I don't know how to get the framework to generate that same datetime format.

While EntityFrameworkCore is still kinda new, it seems like this is a pretty straightforward use case, so I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong and that it's not a framework issue.

**How do I prevent EF from generating an invalid datetime value in the SQL?**

and/or

**How do I get the generated SQL to use another format for DateTime objects?**

---

The EntityFramework model I'm using looks like this:

```
public class DeskReading
{
    public int DeskReadingId { get; set; }
    //... some other fields ...
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

And my LINQ to query the values looks like this:

```
IQueryable<DeskReading> readings = 
    _dbContext.DeskReadings
            .OrderBy(gr => gr.Timestamp)
            .Where(gr => gr.Timestamp > new DateTime(2017, 05, 01));

readings.ToList();
```

And the SQL that's generated by that looks like this:

```sql
SELECT [gr].[DeskReadingId] --...some other fields ...
FROM [DeskReadings] AS [gr]
WHERE [gr].[Timestamp] > '2017-05-01T00:00:00.0000000'
ORDER BY [gr].[Timestamp]
```

Note that the value for the filter is `'2017-05-01T00:00:00.0000000'`

If I run that SQL directly on the SqlServer via SSMS, I get the same error:

[image]

But if I change the filter to use `'2017-05-01 00:00:00'`, it works fine:

```sql
SELECT [gr].[DeskReadingId] --...some other fields ...
FROM [DeskReadings] AS [gr]
WHERE [gr].[Timestamp] > '2017-05-01 00:00:00'
ORDER BY [gr].[Timestamp]
```

As requested, here's the create script for the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DeskReadings](
    [DeskReadingId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SoilMoistureSensor1] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SoilMoistureSensor2] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LightLevel] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TemperatureF] [real] NOT NULL,
    [HumidityPercent] [real] NOT NULL,
    [Timestamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.DeskReadings] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [DeskReadingId] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: What happens if you do `new DateTime(2017, 05, 01)` **outside** of the LINQ.

Comment: @mjwills I used the extension method found in this post to get the SQL: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51583047/682840   Considering it generates the same SqlException at runtime, I'm fairly confident this is the correct.

Comment: See twitter where I answered your question :P, If correct, I'll add it here...

Comment: Bringing this conv from twitter: https://twitter.com/Wright2Tweet/status/1034254345196527616

Using that same datetime format with Sql type `datetime2` works, but for type `datetime` it fails with the original error.

Comment: @JohnM.Wright Why do you think it's a bug? If the table was created by EFC migration, the column type would be `datetime2`. Looks like you created it manually (or are mapping to existing database), then it's normal to tell EFC that the column type is `datetime` with data annotation or fluent API. Remember that EFC queries / behaviors are based on the model metadata, not the actual database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In looking at the source code on **GitHub**, there is a conditional formatting that **EntityFrameworkCore** uses based on the StoreType it believes the column in the expression to be. For example, the format you're seeing is clearly for `datetime2`. The error that you're experiencing can occur when comparing a `datetime` column to a `datetime2` formatted string.

Here is the source I'm referring to, there are three string consts that represent the format for the C# `DateTime` value:

```cs
    private const string DateFormatConst = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}";
    private const string DateTimeFormatConst = "{0:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffK}";
    private const string DateTime2FormatConst = "{0:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffK}";
```

**Formats**
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/release/2.2/src/EFCore.SqlServer/Storage/Internal/SqlServerDateTimeTypeMapping.cs#L18-L20

**Conditional Logic**
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/release/2.2/src/EFCore.SqlServer/Storage/Internal/SqlServerDateTimeTypeMapping.cs#L70-L74

To fix this specific issue, you can attribute your model as such:

```
public class DeskReading
{
    public int DeskReadingId { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName="datetime")]
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

This will force comparisons to treat it as a `StoreType` of `datetime` and correctly format it.

Comment: For those interested, I did end up filing an Issue with the EntityFrameworkCore project to have it utilize the `DateTimeFormatConst` instead of the `DateTime2FormatConst` in this case.  https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/13133

Comment: The default is `datetime2` for `DateTime` property. You need to configure your property in EF Core model if you want to use `datetime` on server.