# How to Use Dates in Where Clause in EF Core?

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, ef-core-2.2

I need to filter my queries by dates but I don't care in this case about time portion of it that is stored in SQL Database.

I first tried to something like

```
var now = DateTime.Now.Date;
Where(x => x.CreatedDate.Date.Compare(now) == 0)
```

but this seems to all get locally checked making the query slow. How can I do this without making it do the check locally?

I am pretty much trying to just find all results that would say have happened today(2020-01-06).

Comment: Why not to simply use this?: `Where(x => x.CreatedDate.Date == now)` It should execute on server

Comment: I think that still gets translated locally,

Comment: No. On server.
Just checked that `WHERE(CreatedDate.Date == now)` translates to
`WHERE ((CONVERT(date, [x].[CreatedDate]) = '2019-01-01T00:00:00.000')`

Comment: weird, let me try again as in my logs it said it would be converted locally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a limited number of methods you can use on translatable types when constructing your Lambda / Linq expressions. This is because each method would need additional code so that it could be translated into a sql store expression. It means that you must check that any methods you want to use and expect to be translated into a sql store expression are supported.

In this case the `DateTime.Compare` is not supported.

The easiest thing to do here is a simple range comparison because the time is included in your persisted value.

```
var start = DateTime.Now.Date;
var end = start.AddDays(1);

Where(x => x.CreatedDate >= start && x.CreatedDate < end)
```

This will result in a [sargable](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-use-sargable-expressions-in-t-sql-queries-performance-advantages-and-examples/) query.

Comment: Yeah, .Date does not seem supported, how do I check if they are valid without writing the code first and waiting to see the error log.

Comment: @chobo2 - You can check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/canonical-functions

Comment: Just checked regarding DateTime.Date.
Verified that `WHERE(CreatedDate.Date == now)` translates to
`WHERE ((CONVERT(date, [x].[CreatedDate]) = '2019-01-01T00:00:00.000')`

Comment: @tgralex - good to know. Even though that code might be easier to read it will result in a non-sargable query though as the query optimizer can't take advantage of any indexes that exist on `CreatedDate` (because of `CONVERT`).

Comment: Just checked on a table which has 200K records with index by that datetime field. Estimated execution shows no difference whether with or without convert.
SQL Servers are quite smart nova days...

Comment: @tgralex - so it is.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
var now = DateTime.Now.Date
...WHERE(CreatedDate.Date == now)
```

I just checked that above translates to the following SQL query:

```
WHERE ((CONVERT(date, [x].[CreatedDate]) = '2019-01-07T00:00:00.000')
```

I used this ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37527783/get-sql-code-from-an-entity-framework-core-iqueryablet/44180537#44180537)) method to see what LINQ translates to