# How to SaveChanges in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

I'm trying to add a controller for the ApplicationUser.cs so that when a admin is logged in, they have the ability to view, edit, delete any records from the dbo.AspNetUsers table however I think I'm doing it wrong. This run with Error "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."Any idea?

AdminController:

```
public AdminController (ApplicationDbContext application)
{
    _application = application;

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult ActiveUser() { return View();}


        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ActiveUser(ApplicationUser Model)
        {
            var active = await _application.Users.FindAsync(Model.Email);

            Model.IsActive = true;
            active.IsActive = (Model.IsActive==true);

         await _application.SaveChangesAsync(); 

            return View();
        }
```

View : `   @model ApplicationUser

```
            <input asp-for="IsActive" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="IsActive" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">ok</button>`
```

Answer (score 2):

You are actually never setting the IsActive on the user object. Note there is a difference between '=' and '=='.

Try this code:

```
 ApplicationUser active = await _application.Users.FindAsync(Model.Email);
 active.IsActive = true;
 _application.Update(active);
 await _application.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: I did as you said "          [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult ActiveUser() { return View();}


        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ActiveUser(ApplicationUser Model)
        {
            ApplicationUser active = await _application.Users.FindAsync(Model.Email);
            
            active.IsActive = Model.IsActive;
            _application.Update(active);
            await _application.SaveChangesAsync();


            return View();
        }
 "

Comment: Are you actually setting the IsActive to true in the view ?

Comment: No.but now i change it and compiler can't accepted " active.IsActive = (active.IsActive == true); " iv View

Comment: I have changed my answer. Please try the updated code.

Comment: should I make new table and put these information there? how to set IsActive in view?

Comment: Sorry I am not sure what do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

The error message indicates you are trying to access properties from a null reference. Based on the code provided, there are two probable causes:

1. The "await _application.Users.FindAsync(Model.Email);" is not finding the user and returning null, hence, when you try to do "active.IsActive = (Model.IsActive==true);" you get the exception.
2. The "Model" variable is not getting an instance and you are getting a null reference exception. You need to verify you are sending the payload in the "POST" and, also, decorate the "Model" parameter with "[FromBody]" attribute. See below:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> ActiveUser([FromBody]ApplicationUser Model)
{
  // Always check the parameters....
  if (Model == null)
  {
     return View();
  }

  var active = await _application.Users.FindAsync(Model.Email);

  // Always verify if found...
  if (active == null)
  {
    Response.StatusCode=404;
    return View(); 
  }

  active.IsActive = (Model.IsActive==true);

  await _application.SaveChangesAsync(); 

  return View();
}
```

Comment: When submitting the post... Are you able to get to "ActiveUser" function?...or...Do you get the "ERROR 415" on submitting the post?... It appears to be  problem related to the "Content-Type" header missing or with the wrong type. Also, try removing the "[FromBody]" attribute IF you are sending the data in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign value for `Model.IsActive`:

```
if (active.IsActive == false) 
{ 
    Model.IsActive = (active.IsActive == true); 
}
_application.Update(active);
await _application.SaveChangesAsync(); 
return View();
```

Comment: still not changing

Comment: try to see whether the other fields are changed, e.g. `Model.FirstName = "Joseph"`;

Comment: No.no changes happend

Comment: It looks like EntityFramework does not generate `UPDATE` sql code. Could you see what SQL code is generated?

Comment: How should MyView be?maybe it's because of myView.

Comment: @Mohadese99 You can see here [what SQL is generated by Entity Framework here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37527783/get-sql-code-from-an-entity-framework-core-iqueryablet)

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems correct. But it seems that you need to pass `model` object to `View`. In your case it seems that your `View` will need object `active` to be passed.

Try `return View(active);` instead of `return View()`.