# SQLite foreign key constraint failed using EF Core to add to child collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1, microsoft.data.sqlite

An order is already inserted in the SQLite database using EF Core. Trying to add an order detail to that order as below, `SaveChanges` throws an exception

> SQLite Error 19: 'FOREIGN KEY constraint failed'

Code:

```
using (DataContext dbase = new())
{
    string orderId = "ef5011f6-8fa0-4483-a9bd-2a2b7de73ba6";

    Order order = dbase.Orders.Include(o => o.OrderDetails).Single(o => o.OrderId == orderId);

    v11OrderDetail.ItemDescription = v10OrderDetail.ItemDescription;
    v11OrderDetail.NrUnits = v10OrderDetail.NrUnits;
    v11OrderDetail.OrderDetailId = v10OrderDetail.OrderDetailId;
    v11OrderDetail.UnitCost = v10OrderDetail.UnitCost;
    v11OrderDetail.UnitPrice = v10OrderDetail.UnitPrice;
    v11OrderDetail.Order = order;
    v11OrderDetail.OrderId = order.OrderId;

    order.OrderDetails.Add(v11OrderDetail);

    dbase.SaveChanges();
}
```

Before calling `SaveChanges` I can see that `order` is correctly populated from the database, `v11OrderDetail.Order` is the saved order and `v11OrderDetail.OrderId` is also correct.

The `OrderDetail` class looks like this

```
public class OrderDetail
{
    private string _OrderDetailId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    public string OrderDetailId
    {
        get { return _OrderDetailId; }
        set { _OrderDetailId = value; }
    }

    private string _OrderId;
    public string OrderId
    {
        get { return Order.OrderId; }
        set { _OrderId = Order.OrderId; }
    }

    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }

    private string? _JobId;
    public string? JobId
    {
        get { return Job?.JobId; }
        set { _JobId = Job?.JobId; }
    }

    public virtual Job? Job { get; set; } // may be null for item sales

    private string _ItemCode;
    public string ItemCode
    {
        get { return _ItemCode; }
        set
        {
            if (value.Length > Defaults.StockCodeLength)
                value = value.Substring(0, Defaults.StockCodeLength);
            _ItemCode = value;
        }
    }

    private string _ItemDescription = Defaults.Description;
    public string ItemDescription
    {
        get { return _ItemDescription; }
        set
        {
            if (value.Equals(_ItemDescription))
                return;
            if (value.Length > Defaults.DescriptionLength)
                value = value.Substring(0, Defaults.DescriptionLength);
            _ItemDescription = value;
        }
    }
  
    public decimal UnitCost { get; set; }

    private int _NrUnits = 1;
    public int NrUnits
    {
        get { return _NrUnits; }
        set
        {
            if (value < 1)
                throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(NrUnits)} cannot be < 1");
            _NrUnits = value;
        }
    }

    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal Net => Total / (1 + Order.TaxRate / 100);
    public decimal Tax => Total - Net;
    public decimal Total => NrUnits * UnitPrice;

    public OrderDetail(string itemCode)
    {
        this._ItemCode = itemCode;
    }
}
```

The `OrderDetail` collection is declared in the `Order` class

```
public virtual ICollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; private set; } = new ObservableCollection<OrderDetail>();
```

In the `DataContext`

```
public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
public DbSet<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }

modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
            .HasKey(e => e.OrderId);
modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
            .Property(e => e.OrderId)
            .ValueGeneratedNever();
modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
            .HasOne(o => o.Customer)
            .WithMany(c => c.Orders)
            .HasForeignKey(o => o.CustomerId);
modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
            .HasOne(o => o.ReferralSource)
            .WithMany(r => r.Orders)
            .HasForeignKey(o => o.ReferralSourceId);
modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
            .HasOne(o => o.StaffMember)
            .WithMany(s => s.Orders)
            .HasForeignKey(o => o.StaffId);
modelBuilder.Entity<OrderDetail>()
            .HasKey(e => e.OrderDetailId);
modelBuilder.Entity<OrderDetail>()
            .Property(e => e.OrderDetailId)
            .ValueGeneratedNever();
modelBuilder.Entity<OrderDetail>()
            .HasOne(d => d.Order)
            .WithMany(o => o.OrderDetails)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.OrderId);
modelBuilder.Entity<OrderDetail>()
            .HasOne(o => o.Job)
            .WithOne(j => j.OrderDetail)
            .IsRequired(false)
            .HasForeignKey<Job>(jfk => jfk.OrderDetailId);
```

StackTrace

```
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc, sqlite3 db)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader.NextResult()
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
```

in a .NET 5.0 class library with

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite 5.01
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies 5.01
```

I've been able to enter the same data using a SQLite database editor so it appears to be my code rather than the data.

EDIT 1: The `CREATE TABLE` statement for `OrderDetails` is

```
CREATE TABLE [OrderDetails] (
    [OrderDetailId] text   NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE
    ,[OrderId] text   NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE
    ,[JobId] text   NULL COLLATE NOCASE
    ,[ItemCode] text   NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE
    ,[ItemDescription] text   NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE
    ,[UnitCost] numeric   NOT NULL 
    ,[NrUnits] integer   NOT NULL 
    ,[UnitPrice] numeric   NOT NULL 
    ,PRIMARY KEY ([OrderDetailId])
    FOREIGN KEY ( [OrderDetailId]) REFERENCES [Jobs]( [JobId] )

    FOREIGN KEY ( [OrderId]) REFERENCES [Orders]( [OrderId] )
);
```

I have implemented [Simple Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/simple-logging). The failure statement output by EF is

```
Failed executing DbCommand (47ms) [Parameters=[@p0='6d9d6827-df81-486f-9759-d50390dda980' (Nullable = false) (Size = 36), @p1='16' (Nullable = false) (Size = 2), @p2='Description' (Nullable = false) (Size = 11), @p3=NULL, @p4='1' (DbType = String), @p5='ef5011f6-8fa0-4483-a9bd-2a2b7de73ba6' (Nullable = false) (Size = 36), @p6='25.59' (DbType = String), @p7='44.8' (DbType = String)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      INSERT INTO "OrderDetails" ("OrderDetailId", "ItemCode", "ItemDescription", "JobId", "NrUnits", "OrderId", "UnitCost", "UnitPrice")
      VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7);
```

I execute the same command (without parameters) in a SQLIte database editor

```
INSERT INTO "OrderDetails" ("OrderDetailId", "ItemCode", "ItemDescription", "JobId", "NrUnits", "OrderId", "UnitCost", "UnitPrice")
      VALUES ('6d9d6827-df81-486f-9759-d50390dda980', '16', 'Description', NULL, '1', 'ef5011f6-8fa0-4483-a9bd-2a2b7de73ba6', '25.59', '44.8');
```

The row is entered successfully.

How do I add this order detail to the database using EF Core?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the `CREATE TABLE` statements of your generated SQL tables. Also add the SQL statement which was generated by EF when calling `SaveChanges()` (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37527783/get-sql-code-from-an-entity-framework-core-iqueryablet). And provide a [mcve], which will generate the same error message when executed.

Comment: Does the OrderDetailId exist in the Jobs table?

Comment: The order exists. The order detail does not exist.

Comment: @Vague `FOREIGN KEY ( [OrderDetailId]) REFERENCES [Jobs]( [JobId] )`, is that the correct foreign key you want? The `OrderDetailId` column should be a value from the `Jobs` table? Don't you want to use the `OrderDetail.JobId` column instead for the foreign key?

Comment: Yoiks! You are exactly right @Progman. I've stared at this until I'm blue in the face. Please post this as answer and I will mark correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
v11OrderDetail.Order = order;
v11OrderDetail.OrderId = order.OrderId;
order.OrderDetails.Add(v11OrderDetail);
dbase.SaveChanges();
```

Instead of those only do:

```
order.OrderDetails.Add(v11OrderDetail);
dbase.SaveChanges();
```

Or DONT get the order from the database and do:

```
v11OrderDetail.OrderId = "ef5011f6-8fa0-4483-a9bd-2a2b7de73ba6";
dbase.OrderDetails.Add(v11OrderDetail);
dbase.SaveChanges();
```

Since you have the order id already

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but I had already tried those options. I've been nutting away at this issue for some days. In each case the same sql is generated and the same exception thown. The sql appears to be valid as it runs successfully in a SQLite editor.