# How does the IQueryable builds the query?

Tags: c#, sql, iqueryable

I have this project in c# where I have several possible types of conditions, let's say they are title and level just to put it simply.

I'm trying to make the query but I'm not sure if it's built in the correct way.

Cases:

- Title is given, I have to go for all the titles that match that one.
- Level is given, it's the same as title

so I have

```
query = query.Where(x => x.Title == title);
```

and later on

```
query = query.Where(x => x.Level == level)
```

My question is, how does this translate?
Like this:

```
from * myTable WHERE Title = title and Level = level
```

or like this (this is the way I need it)

```
from * myTable WHERE Title = title or Level = level
```

I have to do some validations and I can't create the query in the same place,

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework or Linq 2 Sql? Have you put in tracing to see what the generated sql looks like?

Comment: @DavidL I'm using entity framework, and I have a breakpoint but the object it's kind of weird, I see the expression but says things like this `.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func` and I don't see if it has the and or not

Comment: For EF Core you can see the generated query [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51583047/2501279).

Comment: It does `AND` not `OR`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the same series of operations on `IEnumerable<T>` and `IQueryable<T>` with the same contents should produce the same output... give or take case sensitive comparisons and so on.

Consider the following:

```
int[] data = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
var query = data.Where(i => i > 3);
query = query.Where(i => i < 8);
```

When you enumerate over `query` (which is of type `IEnumerable<int>`) the operations are applied in sequence. Values which fail the first `Where` do not get evaluated by the second, so can never reach the result set:

> | Value | First Where | Second Where | Output |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | Fail | -- | No |
> | 2 | Fail | -- | No |
> | 3 | Fail | -- | No |
> | 4 | Pass | Pass | Yes |
> | 5 | Pass | Pass | Yes |
> | 6 | Pass | Pass | Yes |
> | 7 | Pass | Pass | Yes |
> | 8 | Pass | Fail | No |
> | 9 | Pass | Fail | No |
> | 10 | Pass | Fail | No |

This is equivalent to:

```
query = data.Where(i => i > 3 && i < 8);
```

The equivalent SQL `WHERE` would then be:

```
WHERE i > 3 AND i < 8
```

---

While this works in the case of restrictive filters (where each term *must* applied), it doesn't do much for permissive filters (where any term *may* apply). Instead we have to look at other ways to do query composition.

For `IEnumerable<T>` we can simply use function composition:

```
string title = "A Title";
int level = 1;

Func<recordType, bool> predicate = x => x.Title == title;
predicate = x => predicate(x) || x.Level == level;

var query = data.Where(predicate);
```

Unfortunately this isn't quite as simple for `IQueryable<T>` since the predicate type is a LINQ `Expression` of type `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`, and we can't create a suitable expression tree from a `Func<T, bool>`. Instead we have to do lambda expression composition.

The simplest point to start at is implementing an `OrElse` expression compositor that takes two lambda expressions and invokes them as parameters to an `OrElse` expression:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> OrElse<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> left, Expression<Func<T, bool>> right)
{
    if (left is null)
        return right;
    
    if (right is null)
        return left;
    
    var parm = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "row");
    var result = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
    (
        Expression.OrElse
        (
            Expression.Invoke(left, parm),
            Expression.Invoke(right, parm)
        ),
        parm
    );
    return result;
}
```

(This could be an extension method, but I think it's bad form to design extensions that explicitly permit targets.)

We can then use this to compose a predicate expression from optional parts:

```
// 'Book' in this case is a placeholder for your record type.
Expression<Func<Book, bool>> MakePermissiveFilter(string title, int? level)
{
    Expression<Func<Book, bool>> result = null;
    
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(title))
        result = OrElse(result, b => b.Title == title);
    
    if (level is not null)
        result = OrElse(result, b => b.Level == level);
    
    // if nothing selected return a default 'always true' predicate
    if (result is null)
        result = b => true;
    
    return result;
}
```

Now we can invoke that to generate the required filter expression for your `Where` clause:

```
// 'query' previously defined with select and optional ordering
query = query.Where(MakePermissiveFilter(text, level));
```

This will work for any compliant `IQueryable<T>`: LinqToObjects, LinqToSQL, Entity Framework (all versions) and so on.

---

The resultant predicate is slightly inelegant, but SQL generation will reduce the noise in most cases. You might end up with a `WHERE 1 = 1` in there if the filter terms are empty.

We could go a lot further and unwrap the supplied lamdba expressions, replace their parameters and build a new lambda, but it's a fair amount of work for relatively little gain.