# Entity Framework Core for custom MySQL Functions, Literals vs Columns

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm attempting to map a MySQL function in EF Core 3.1, .NET Core 3.1. More specifically, I'm trying to map a parameter of type `params object[]`.

The example code below uses `CONCAT()` for illustration purposes.

After some fiddling around with `HasTranslation()` and a custom `RelationalTypeMapping` it works with literals. Meaning it produces the correct SQL query and will execute that query successfully.

As soon as I pass a column it fails to produce the correct SQL query and will throw the `NotSupportedException` upon execution.

There are two issues I'm trying to resolve at this stage:

1. Passing any column will never hit my function configuration, and by extension, my translation.
2. Passing any column results in various (and weird) behaviors with other parameters. This could likely be easily resolved after solving #1, but it's interesting, nonetheless. (i.e. `"asdf"` vs `(object)"asdf"`)

The `ToSql()` extension method used for debugging is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/67901042/1048799

The output is commented in the code.

**Packages**

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="6.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="6.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="MySql.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.17" />
```

**EfTestService.cs**

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EfTest
{
    public interface IEfTestService
    {
        Task RunAsync();
    }

    public class EfTestService : IEfTestService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<IEfTestService> logger;
        private readonly EfTestDbContext dbContext;

        public EfTestService(ILogger<IEfTestService> logger, EfTestDbContext dbContext)
        {
            this.logger = logger;
            this.dbContext = dbContext;
        }

        public async Task RunAsync()
        {
            var concat0 = dbContext.TestRecords.Select(r => dbContext.Concat(0, 1, "2", 3.0d, 4.0m, "five"));
            var concat0Sql = concat0.ToSql();
            //var concat0Result = await concat0.FirstAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(concat0Sql);

            /*
             * works as expected
             * 
                SELECT `CONCAT`(0, 1, '2', 3, 4.0, 'five')
                FROM `TestRecords` AS `t`
            */

            var concat1 = dbContext.TestRecords.Select(r => dbContext.Concat(r.TestRecordId));
            var concat1Sql = concat1.ToSql();
            //var concat1Result = await concat1.FirstAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(concat1Sql);

            /* 
             * not CONCAT
             * 
                SELECT `t`.`TestRecordId`
                FROM `TestRecords` AS `t`
            */

            var concat2 = dbContext.TestRecords.Select(r => dbContext.Concat(r.TestRecordId, 0.1)); 
            var concat2Sql = concat2.ToSql();
            //var concat2Result = await concat2.FirstAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(concat2Sql);

            /* 
             * not CONCAT, 0.1 is included
             * 
                SELECT `t`.`TestRecordId`, 0.1
                FROM `TestRecords` AS `t`
            */

            var concat3 = dbContext.TestRecords.Select(r => dbContext.Concat(r.TestRecordId, "asdf")); 
            var concat3Sql = concat3.ToSql();
            //var concat3Result = await concat3.FirstAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(concat3Sql);

            /* 
             * not CONCAT, asdf is NOT included
             * 
                SELECT `t`.`TestRecordId`
                FROM `TestRecords` AS `t`
            */

            var concat4 = dbContext.TestRecords.Select(r => dbContext.Concat(r.TestRecordId, (object)"asdf")); 
            var concat4Sql = concat4.ToSql();
            //var concat4Result = await concat4.FirstAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(concat4Sql);

            /* 
             * not CONCAT, asdf is included
             * 
                SELECT `t`.`TestRecordId`, 'asdf'
                FROM `TestRecords` AS `t`
            */


        }
    }
}
```

**EfTestDbContext.cs**

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressions;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace EfTest
{
    public class EfTestDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public EfTestDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder
                .HasDbFunction(() => Concat(default))
                .HasTranslation(expressions =>
                { /* breakpoint, hit when passing only literals */
                    if (expressions.First() is SqlConstantExpression expression)
                    {
                        if (expression.Value is object[] @params)
                        {
                            var args = @params.Select(p => new SqlConstantExpression(Expression.Constant(p), ObjectTypeMapping.Instance));

                            return SqlFunctionExpression.Create("`CONCAT`", args, typeof(string), null);
                        }
                    }

                    throw new InvalidOperationException();
                })
                .HasParameter("vals").Metadata.TypeMapping = RelationalTypeMapping.NullMapping;
        }

        [DbFunction("CONCAT")]
        public string Concat(params object[] vals)
            => throw new NotSupportedException(); /* thown at execution when passing a column */

        public DbSet<TestRecord> TestRecords { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestRecord
    {
        public int TestRecordId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**ObjectTypeMapping.cs**

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage;
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace EfTest
{
    public class ObjectTypeMapping : RelationalTypeMapping
    {
        public static readonly ObjectTypeMapping Instance = new ObjectTypeMapping();

        public ObjectTypeMapping() : base("object", typeof(object), System.Data.DbType.Object, true) { }

        protected override RelationalTypeMapping Clone(RelationalTypeMappingParameters parameters)
            => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public override string GenerateSqlLiteral(object value)
        {
            if (value is string strValue)
            {
                strValue = Regex.Replace(strValue, @"([\\])", @"\$1");

                if (!strValue.Contains("'"))
                {
                    return $"'{strValue}'";
                }
                else if (!strValue.Contains('"'))
                {
                    return $"\"{strValue}\"";
                }
                else
                {
                    strValue = Regex.Replace(strValue, "(['\"])", @"\$1");

                    return $"'{strValue}'";
                }
            }

            return base.GenerateSqlLiteral(value);
        }
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EfTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            IHost host = null;

            try
            {
                host = CreateHostBuilder(null).Build();

                var efTestService = ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance<IEfTestService>(host.Services);
                
                await host.StartAsync();
                await efTestService.RunAsync();
                await host.WaitForShutdownAsync();
            }
            finally
            {
                host?.Dispose();
            }
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddDbContext<EfTestDbContext>(
                        options => options.UseMySQL(
                            context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
                        )
                    );

                    services.AddSingleton<IEfTestService, EfTestService>();
                });

            return builder;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For the purposes of the bounty, more modern versions of .NET/EF are acceptable.

Comment: Is there a function to "serialize" an "object"?

Comment: @RickJames Sorry I don't quite follow... Are you referring to the `ObjectTypeMapping` code?

Comment: Do you really need `object[]` argument (because generally it's a problem since is not supported even in the latest at this time EFC 6.0)? Can you provide more realistic example? How many items are supposed to be in the array? Are you open for alternatives?

Comment: @IvanStoev The bounty is for a solution to the problem as presented.

Comment: Forget about bounty - I'm pretty sure it will be wasted anyway. As I said, such arguments are not supported by EFC infrastructure code. I can solve it by hooking into EFC infrastructure (which itself is tedious and requires a lot of boilerplate code), but not sure it's worth enough. Especially for something that could easily break in any future version (as indicated by the "internal API" warnings they put everywhere in their far from perfect infrastructure). I like the challenges, but only if they make sense and are useful for other people. Which doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: Anyway, in case I have some time and decide to spend it on this, I need to know which MySql [provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) (yes, the *provider* package) are you using - Pomelo or from Oracle?

Comment: @IvanStoev Oracle

Comment: As I thought, no one (including me) wish to spend time on this.  The answers to all your questions and weird behaviors is contained in `RelationalSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor` class [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/main/src/EFCore.Relational/Query/RelationalSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.cs). You have to replace it with your own and intercept `VisitMethodCall` and do your translation there. But note that db providers have their inherited classes, and the ...

Comment: ...[Oracle one](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-net/blob/8.0/EFCore6/src/Query/Internal/MySQLSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.cs) as usual is not following EF Core design guidelines and is made `internal` rather than `public`, so it's impossible to be inherited. The only option is to copy/paste it and add your modifications. Then all you need is to replace `IRelationalSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitorFactory` service with your own in order to allocate your expression visitor. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

> Passing any column will never hit my function configuration, and by extension, my translation.

It is impossible to map `params object[]` to any EF class directly.

Each parameter must be well defined with a type and count.

Unwind the variations of input and cast to the appropriate EF structure/class prior to mapping.

Yes, lots of data and mapping classes.