# Can I use Entity Framework Core to generate SQL from an expression stored as a string?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

If I have an Entity Framework expression stored as a string, like this:

```
var exp = "from user in users where user.Id == 1 select user.Name";
```

Is there a way to convert this to SQL using EF Core?

I don't need to run the SQL, just get the SQL that would be generated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to run linq expression stored in `string` variable. For that purposes you need to import `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting`.

Here the snippet you can run with

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting;

var users = new List<User>() { new User { Id = 1, Name = "John" }, new User { Id = 2, Name = "Jane" } };
var exp = "from user in users where user.Id == 1 select user.Name";

ScriptOptions options = ScriptOptions.Default.AddReferences(typeof(User).Assembly);
options = options.AddImports("System.Linq");

var filteredUsers = await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<IEnumerable<string>>(exp, options, new Globals{ users = users });

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
}

public class Globals
{
    public List<User> users;
}
```

So if you can execute an expression, you also can compile it to sql query. Hopefully `ToQueryString()` [link1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.toquerystring?view=efcore-5.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions_ToQueryString_System_Linq_IQueryable_) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51583047/2091519) inside the string expression can help you to get the sql string

Hope it helps

Comment: Hello, thanks for the suggestion. In this instance I don't actually want to run the expression, instead i want to convert the expression to a SQL query.

Comment: just edited the answer. I get you. So you can add more references in the sample above and run `ToQueryString()` instead of just returning result

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended as sql injection can done through this technique. imagine ur storing sql query like drop table tablename it will drop ur data.

Comment: As i mentioned, i won't be running the sql, i just want the converted sql as a string.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).