# Enable raw SQL logging in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How do I enable the logging of DbCommand raw SQL queries?

I have added the following code to my Startup.cs file, but do not see any log entries from the Entity Framework Core.

```
void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddLogging();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug(LogLevel.Debug);
}
```

I'm expecting to see something like this:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommandBuilder...
SELECT [t].[Id], [t].[DateCreated], [t].[Name], [t].[UserName]
FROM [Trips] AS [t]
```

Answer (score 6):

From MVC Core 2, logging SQL is the default behaviour. Just make sure logging level in appSettings json file is correct.

```
"Logging": {
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Debug",
    "System": "Information",
    "Microsoft": "Information"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out - need to configure DbContext to use logger factory.

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);

    optionsBuilder.UseLoggerFactory(_loggerFactory);
}
```

Comment: Just to note to others reading the above code: the `_loggerFactory` parameter is set using constructor dependency injection in your `FooContext` class.

Comment: Just for other who came here with the same problem read out [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging).
As this answer is not very helpful.

Comment: If you use asp.net mvc core, no need to do anything, just make sure that the logging verbosity is "info".

Comment: @meze it does not matter whether you use .NET Core or not, if you're registering your `DbContext` with `services.AddDbContext(...)`. This method assures that applications standard logging factory is already registered, or it throws an exception if it is not able to find one.