# Entity Framework Core / 7 SQL Logging

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Looking at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412863/how-do-i-view-the-sql-generated-by-the-entity-framework) I need to do the same thing, that is I want the SQL to be copied to my Output, but I need it done for `EF Core / 7`

I tried adding the `LogFactory` as is shown in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39282951/enable-raw-sql-logging-in-entity-framework-core)

But that did not produce the SQL output either... what am I missing?

Comment: Do you have your `loggerFactory` configured in `Startup.cs`?

Comment: Show me how to do it please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [EF Core 1.1 example you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39282951/enable-raw-sql-logging-in-entity-framework-core) should work, assuming you have the following in your `Configure` method in your `Startup.cs`:

```
public void Configure(
    IApplicationBuilder application, 
    IHostingEnvironment environment, 
    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) {

        loggerFactory
            .AddConsole(LogLevel.Debug)  // This will output to the console/terminal
            .AddDebug(LogLevel.Debug);   // This will output to Visual Studio Output window

        // Your additional configuration here...
}
```

Comment: Just for other who came here with the same problem read out [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging).
As this answer is not very helpful, except @Matt has added only the scaffolded code.

Comment: But it answered his question :(

Answer (score 0):

You can also install dotnet tools. The repository contains command-line tools for the .NET Core CLI.

Running dotnet watch run, debugs the application as well as showing you any sql queries that are executed.

I am coding with VS code and not 100% sure if it will work in Visual Studio.