# ASP.NET Core 1.1 log all DbContext queries to output window

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

How can I log all queries to output when using `DbContext`?

In the past I get all queries (SQLs) in Output window in Visual studio 2015. I don't know when this has stopped.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, DbSeeder dbSeeder)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();
```

And appsettings.json:

```
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26747837/how-to-log-queries-using-entity-framework-7) is not working. And I think [this](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/7219) means the logs should be in output.

**Edited:**

I think it is not possible without some work around.
[GitHub1](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2795), [GitHub2](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/1199).

For now I went with SQL Server Profiler.

Answer (score 0):

Set the Microsoft LogLevel in appsettings.json to `Debug` or `Verbose`. The default LogLevel is only used if there isn't a more specific level, and Entity Framework looks at the Microsoft level.

`AddConsole` is what makes the affected logs get printed to stdout according to the Logging section you pass in.

Comment: It is not working. For Verbose it returns error: Additional information: Configuration value 'Verbose' for category 'Microsoft' is not supported.

Comment: And when you try "Debug"?

Comment: Try "Trace", they renamed the logging levels.

Comment: Setting Logging:LogLevel:Microsoft to Trace does not help.